# How do I renew my expired Windows Store app certificate?

Tags: windows-store-apps

I have taken over the development of a Windows Store app, and our store certificate has recently expired. How do I renew the certificate, or do I have to generate a new one?

In the .appxmanifest, I can choose to generate a new Test certificate, but I need a *store* certificate, not a test certificate.

Comment: tried right clicking the project -> Store -> Associate?

Comment: The association is apparently still there. I'm starting a full rebuild and will check back tomorrow, to see if the app store likes this one.

Comment: You will have to generate a new certificate. If your store association is still active, I believe it will handle your store certificate automatically.

Comment: Try removing the certificate and then associate the app with the Store again?

Comment: I just did this the other day... you have to do as @Mikael says and associate the app with the store (there is no need to remove the existing cert). You will get a wizard that walks you through the association - on the page where you select app names, you will have to check the box next to "include app names that already have packages". Then select the existing app and finish the wizard.

Comment: I haven't removed the certificate, but I did re-do the association.  WACK was failing with 0x80073d05, which apparently means "certificate out of date". Purging the Generated Files and Release (and a few other files) was required. WACK has now passed, but we're not yet ready to submit so we'll see how that goes in a week or so. Looks like it's now working.

Comment: Ran into the same problem but this is now 2020 and the above doesn't seem to solve it. At the first attempt, the Associate step did at least show my existing apps, but now reliably returns an "unexpected network error" and will go no further. Creating a test certificate doesn't change the situation. I've posted this to VS problems and hope that someone at MS can offer information.

Comment: [Edit: a Clean and rebuild from scratch fixed the network error, after which the Associate command did the trick. I should have thought of Clean, the all-purpose solution.

Answer (score 23):

You need to:

1. Generate new test certificate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230260.aspx#Renew
2. Associate with store app: Project -> Store -> Associate

Comment: This worked, THANK YOU! The key step was #1, you have to change the test certificate, otherwise a new store certificate won't be generated.

Comment: What knind of windows app it is about?

Answer (score 2):

The answer here got outdated, so [here's how to renew a test certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/create-certificate-package-signing#create-a-self-signed-certificate) in year 2019:

1. Open *Powershell*
2. Paste:

   ```
   New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -Subject "CN=Contoso Software, O=Contoso Corporation, C=US" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -FriendlyName "Contoso app test certificate" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3", "2.5.29.19={text}")
   ```

   **-Subject**

   The `-Subject` here **must** match the "Publisher" section in your app's manifest.

   For example, the "`Identity`" section in your app's `AppxManifest.xml` file should look something like this:

   The "Publisher", in this case, is `CN=Contoso Software, O=Contoso Corporation, C=US` which needs to be used in `-Subject` option for creating your certificate.

   **-FriendlyName**

   The `-FriendlyName` option is a friendly name for the certificate.
3. Go to *Package.appxmanifest*, *Package* tab, *Select certificate* button, select the one you have just created.

Comment: Can this (self signed)  be used for the store?

Comment: @peterc no, for the Store you have to associate your app with the Store and use the provided certificate

Comment: Yes thought so. So you DO need to use Visual Studio for that. There is no way to do that without Visual Studio (from what i have seen)

Comment: Yes - and as I noted above, VS currently seems to have a problem with this. A few days ago it was at least able to show my other apps in the Associate wizard but now just reports an "unexpected network error."

Answer (score 2):

- Open Packaging.appxmanifest with Visual Studio
- Go to the Packaging tab
- Press Choose Certificate
- From dropdown select Create test certificate.

Comment: While the OP asked for a Store Certificate specifically, I needed a Test Certificate and this answer helped me.

Comment: You can use a test certificate for the Store without problems.

Comment: That may have changed (2023) - I created a test certificate, associated with store, uploaded, validated and published. Partner Center now shows the new app and its new screen images, etc. as "in the Store" but after 2 days it still does not appear to customers - only the old version appears. I think this  must somehow relate to the new certificate not really working like the expired one.